# Convert a data frame in R to a polygon for viewing in Google Earth

Tags: r, kml, google-earth, visualisation, data-frame

I have a dataframe in R which contains numerous columns of lat long coordinates. Each row of the data frame contains 9 x lat/long coor points.

I wish to plot each of these rows in Google Earth using the plotKML function or any other R package for that matter since I can only use R V2.14.0!!

Ideally I would like to continue using v3.x.x but plotKML doesn't work then so if there's an alternative R->KML package please shout.

I've read up about the differences between polygon and polygons [here](http://www.nickeubank.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/RGIS1_SpatialDataTypes_part1_vectorData.html#spatialpolygons-your-bread-and-butter) but I am having difficulty converting my dataframe to a spatialpolygon in order to plot the data in Google Earth. I suspect it's because I have multiple columns of lat long coordinates and plotKML doesn't know (or I haven't specified correctly) what to do with them.

Can anyone point me in the right direction about how to go about this?

I have a sample of my data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzkBEqPfozOOMGtxeFJoN3J1Q3c) in dput() format if it's of any benefit.

Comment: I used yesterday plotKML in R 3.3.2. Why do you say that?

Comment: Because it says it here on their project page [link](http://plotkml.r-forge.r-project.org/). Every time I tried on 3.3 I got an error when installing the package. Have I missed something here?

Comment: `works only on >= R 2.14`, so it works in R version same or higher than 2.14. Can you paste error message? Even more, plotKML installed in my computer says `Built: R 3.3.0; ; 2016-05-05 18:54:12 UTC; unix` for `Package: plotKML
Version: 0.5-6
Date: 2016-05-02`

Comment: > library(plotKML)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘chron’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘plotKML’ was built under R version 3.3.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plotKML’

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: You need to install `chron` package before `plotKML`. Try with `install.packages('plotKML', dependencies = T)` or `install.packages('plotKML', dependencies= c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances"))`

Comment: @aldo_tapia I tried both commands above and I got the following error: Error in fetch(key) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/J/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/plotKML/help/plotKML.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: Follow steps posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424608/error-in-fetchkey-lazy-load-database)

Comment: You can build SpatialPolygonsDataFrame objects with sptable::sp, happy to help here but I can't access google drive right now.

Comment: @aldo_tapia thanks for the tips and links, I uninstalled older versions of R, searched for *.rdb files and noticed I had some in c:/windows.old/ so I did a disk clean up. I then installed chron via tools->install packages and then successfully installed plotKML. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @mdsumner no problem thanks for the steer, if you do get access to the data and have some recommendations please shout. Thanks again.

Comment: I put it here so it's more generally accessible: run source on this to create "d" data frame: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mdsumner/71d75ae0275a055864797b6d5445e375/raw/dd3d488179c5df8354fcef6b538d19bd5285735c/sample1.r  But I don't see which 9 pairs are obviously lon and lat?  Is there a polygon per row? which columns? there are 70 here.

Comment: @mdsumner as commented on GitHub [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkBEqPfozOOTWRWUmNLXzNxUGc/view?usp=sharing) is the revised file. Columns 71-88 are the coordinates I am interested in plotting in Google Earth. I plan to pass some of the other variables and attributes for aesthetics later on but if I can first plot them I would be really happy. Sorry one again for the mix up.

Comment: I am again in a place I cannot access drive, feel free to paste it into the gist comment :)